# admob AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID

Tags: android, admob

I try to add an **Interstitial ads**, the problem is that i have 2 code to change.

The 2 codes to change in my `MainActivity`:

[image]

But in my **admob** account, I can only find the `ca-app-pub-xxxxx....xx`  code and I can't find the `ID_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID.`

Can any body please show me where to find the second one?

I tried to put the same links in the two code but I am afraid of being banned from **admob**.

Comment: You only need the "ca-app-pub" id, I don't know what the other is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need only `<string name="interstitial_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>`
and do this on you onCreate() method

```
//region Interstitial
    String interstitialAdId=getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(interstitialAdId);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed()
        {
        }
    });
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    //endregion
```

then add

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
        mInterstitialAd.show();
```

where you want to start the Interstitial